# Visual SVN : Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with no output

Tags: svn, jira, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I'm using Visual-SVN v.3.5 to commit the code in SVN server using JIRA key.. While I committing the code with proper commit message, I'm getting the issue (Which I have shown in image).

**NOTE : And it is successfully committed if I'm not using any rule policies in JIRA.**

[image]

Please help me to fix this issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also got the same issue, and I fixed it by doing the following..

- If you observe the hooks folder you should replace the
  pre-commit.tmpl file with the **pre-commit** file which will we get from the Jira.
- **and one more thing is you need to set the python path in your environment variables.**

Comment: And I have created python with 32 bit as my machine having compatible of 64bit.